# JSON Cross domain using AJAX Not working with ie

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am using Ajax do do cross domain calls using JSON, and the script works fine in FF but in ie the script will not populate the `select menu` with the results, in ie it will display errors so i know the script is definitely working and making cross domain calls, can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
function xss_ajax(url) {

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', url);
    script.setAttribute('id', 'script_id');

    script_id = document.getElementById('script_id');
    if (script_id) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(script_id);
    }


    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

    document.getElementById("addrlist").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("errlog").innerHTML = "";
}

function callback(data) {

    if (typeof data['error'] != "undefined") {
        if (window.on_error) {
            on_error();
        }

        if (document.getElementById("errlog")) {
            document.getElementById("errlog").innerHTML = "<br>" + data['error'] + "<br>";
        } else {
            alert(data['error']);
        }

    } else {



        var val = data['address1'] + ", " + data['address2'] + ", " + data['address3'] + ", " + data['address4'] + ", " + data['postcode'];

        document.getElementById("addrlist").innerHTML += "<option value='" + val + "'>" + val + "</option>";

    }
}

function searchpost() {

    var license = '98798797';
    var url = "http://mydomin.co.uk/myfile.php?postcode=" + escape(document.getElementById("field1").value) + '&license=' + escape(license);

    xss_ajax(url);

}
```

Comment: requesting for JSON file or JS file?

Comment: @MihaiIorga: It's actually a JSONP request, so it's the code that adds a script tag to the head.

Comment: @K.K: Both. It's a JSONP call, so it's JSON wrapped in `callback(...)` to make it a Javscript file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is the way that you add the options to the select. Create a new option element and add to the select element instead of replacing all the HTML content:

```
var opt = document.createElement('OPTION');
opt.text = val;
opt.value = val;
document.getElementById("addrlist").options.add(opt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library to make things easier:

```
var license = '98798797';
var url = "http://mydomin.co.uk/myfile.php?postcode="+escape($("#field1").val())+'&license='+escape(license);

$.getJSON(url+'&callback=?', function(data) {
    var val = data.address1 + ", " + data.address2 + ", " + data.address3 + ", " + data.address4 + ", " + data.postcode;
    var opt = $('option').text(val).val(val);
    $("#addrlist").append(opt); 
});
```

See how short your code is now?

Btw you treated your json data as an array and it's not an array so instead of (for example): `data['address1']` I changed it to `data.address1` because a parsed json is an object.

In addition I deleted all the error checking because its simply not nescessary.

*p.s I added the `callback=?` to make it a **JSONP** ajax request because jsonp is for cross-domain ajax.*

Comment: In his code, but when i'm doing it jQuery way i need to add that.

Comment: It's not a normal ajax request i ment.